# Android Kotlin can't use spinner inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-spinner

I am trying to use a spinner inside a fragment but whenever I click on it nothing happens (meaning it doesn't show me anything to select)

```
private fun prioritySpinner() {
    //the array with all the string values
    val searchPriority = resources.getStringArray(R.array.PriorityArray)

    // Initializing an ArrayAdapter
    val adapter = context?.let {
        ArrayAdapter(
            it, // Context
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, // Layout
            searchPriority // Array
        )
    }

    // Set the drop down view resource
    adapter?.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line)

    //searchPriority_ShowBugsFragment_spinner is my spinner
    // Finally, data bind the spinner object with adapter
    searchPriority_ShowBugsFragment_spinner?.adapter = adapter

    // Set an on item selected listener for spinner object        
    searchPriority_ShowBugsFragment_spinner?.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onItemSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long){
            // Display the selected item text on text view
            Toast.makeText(context,"Selected "+ searchPriority[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>){
            // Another interface callback
        }
    }

}
```

It doesn't change anything if I call the function inside the onCreateView or inside the onCreate

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    prioritySpinner()
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_bugs,container,false)

}
```

or

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    prioritySpinner()

}
```

Comment: try `prioritySpinner()` in `onViewCreated` callback hook

Comment: tried using it like this : 

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        prioritySpinner()
    }

but it still does nothing when I click it